# Is glycine achiral?

Tags: biochemistry, chirality, amino-acids

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhwAp6yQHQI) (10:20>) the woman says that the Glycine is not *[chiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(chemistry))* because it has 2 different group only rather than four.

Then I can understand from her things that *amino acid* can be chiral just in case that it has 4 different groups. But I don't understand why when even it has only two different groups it can not be chiral, here is the group of the left side can be on the right and vice versa and this is an a mirror image as well.

Comment: There is a mirror plane that contains the central carbon and bisects the angle between the two hydrogen substituents.

Comment: @Jan I don't think this is a duplicate. The answer may be similar, but the question is quite different.

Comment: Well, my reasoning is that I can see *all* of OP’s question being asked in the potential dupe-target (while that asks more).

Comment: Due two down-votes on my questions and the attitude that I experienced here as a new member here I have the feeling that this site is for phD students rather than for beginners.  I thought it is a site for studding and asking questions chemistry in any level.

Answer (score 1):

It is not chiral because If the amino group and the carboxylic acid group changed places, the "new" arrangement would be superimposable on the old arrangement.